# Intercepting stat call with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, ld, strace

I'm trying to write a shared object that intercepts some filesystem API calls such as open, close, read, write etc., that originate from an application. Interception is done using LD_PRELOAD. I've used strace methodically to find out the APIs called by the application and implement them in the shared library loaded by LD_PRELOAD. When it comes to stat, I found that __xstat and __xstat64 is called instead of stat and I've overridden these two functions. I'm able to trap these API calls. However, in one particular environment, when I use strace I see direct calls to the stat() itself. Like below

```
25083 03:11:28.424859 close(13)         = 0 <0.000045>
>> 25083 03:11:28.424966 stat("/somedir/somefile", 0x7ffe751d2430) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000050>
25083 03:11:28.425067 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {786855, 130369007}) = 0 <0.000029>
```

The difference I note is that stat is called directly which I don't see in other environments. It is possible that the application calls stat() however I see that stat internally calls __xstat or __xstat64. Another thing I noticed is that stat() isn't even implemented in libc.so library. So this stat() appears to be a direct invocation of the stat() system call. How do I confirm this? And how would an application directly invoke stat() system call?

Comment: Strace shows you syscalls, not calls to standard library functions. Syscalls communicate directly with the kernel using a special opcode. On linux, type [man 2 sycalls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a summary

Comment: Also note that the standard library has no magic. Everything it can do, your app can do. Mostly, what it does is to issue syscalls, which can do things not possible in userspace.

Answer (score 4):

> So this stat() appears to be a direct invocation of the stat() system call. How do I confirm this?

Run the program inside of `gdb` with `catch syscall stat`. When the syscall happens, check the call stack with `bt` and take note of whether you're in libc.so.

> And how would an application directly invoke stat() system call?

With inline assembly. Here's an example of it for [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc < 2) return 1;
    struct stat s;
    long rv;
    __asm__ volatile(
        "syscall"
        : "=a"(rv)
        : "a"(SYS_stat), "D"(argv[1]), "S"(&s)
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
    if(rv) return 1;
    printf("%zu\n", s.st_size);
}
```